# WooCommerce- change admin date format

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to change the WooCommerce date format from Y/m/d to d/m/Y. I have the Print invoice plug-in, and the dates are in the y/m/d format as taken from the date ordered in WooCommerce.

The below used to be a solution- but it no longer works for WP 4.0

http://www.remicorson.com/customize-woocommerce-admin-orders-date-format/

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wpse_77783_woo_bacs_ibn', 10, 3);
add_filter( 'post_date_column_time' , 'woo_custom_post_date_column_time' );

// change default admin orders date format
add_filter( 'post_date_column_time' , 'woo_custom_post_date_column_time' );

function woo_custom_post_date_column_time( $post ) {
$h_time = get_the_time( __( 'm/d/Y', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
return $h_time;
}
```

Can anyone advise me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to change the value of '$t_time' variable using the same 'post_date_column_time' filter.You have to return two values ($t_time and $h_time) using two separate callback functions. Your code will work when you add following callback on same filter in addition to your code.

```
 add_filter( 'post_date_column_time' ,'woo_custom_post_date_column_time_withDate' );

 function woo_custom_post_date_column_time_withDate( $post ) {  
$t_time = get_the_time( __( 'd/m/Y g:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
 return $t_time; 
}
```

(Also check the format you have set into the call back function, change it to 'd/m/Y' since you require it.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is no longer valid for newer versions. For version 3 and up, please see [WooCommerce 3.0+ change admin order date column format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331509/woocommerce-3-0-change-admin-order-date-column-format/43333263#43333263).