# WooCommerce 3.0+ change admin order date column format

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce I was using the code below to alter the admin orders view formatting of the order date column:

```
// Woocommerce show time on order
add_filter('post_date_column_time', 'custom_post_date_column_time', 10, 2);
function custom_post_date_column_time($h_time, $post)
{
    return get_the_time(__('Y/m/d g:i:s A', 'woocommerce'), $post);
}
```

Since WooCommerce 3.0+ it has just stopped working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WordPress StackExchange indicates that all WooCommerce questions are off topic. I'd post here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/8628

Comment: Resolved, please see thread at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-time-on-order-backend-broken-since-woo-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE RIGHT ANSWER:**

**Please see the official [WooCommerce answer thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-time-on-order-backend-broken-since-woo-3/)**

> For ease of reference for others, the new filter is due to be released in WooCommerce 3.0.2.

Patch can be manually applied from https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/14253

It works with a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_admin_order_date_format`** new filter hook:

```
// Woocommerce show time on order
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_date_format', 'custom_post_date_column_time');
function custom_post_date_column_time($h_time, $post)
{
    return get_the_time(__('Y/m/d G:i', 'woocommerce'), $post);
}
```

Comment: Under WooCommerce Version 6.7.0, I get Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: 

Too few arguments to function custom_post_date_column_time(), 
1 passed in /.../wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307 
and exactly 2 expected

Answer (score 4):

In WC core code `class-wc-admin-post-types.php` if you look at `render_shop_order_columns()` function, things have changed since WooCommerce version 3.0+, as it uses **`WC_Abstract_Order`** [**`get_date_created()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#254-262) method instead of WordPress function [`get_the_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time).

**So that is why the hook that you are using is not working anymore.**

Here is an extract of the source code in WooCommerce version 3.0+:

```
case 'order_date' :
    printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', esc_attr( $the_order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ), esc_html( $the_order->get_date_created()->date_i18n( __( 'Y-m-d', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) );
break;
```

And Here the same source code extract in  WooCommerce version 2.6.x:

```
case 'order_date' :

    if ( '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post->post_date ) {
        $t_time = $h_time = __( 'Unpublished', 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
        $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
        $h_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d', 'woocommerce' ), $post );
    }

    echo '<abbr title="' . esc_attr( $t_time ) . '">' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'post_date_column_time', $h_time, $post ) ) . '</abbr>';

break;
```

> Now if you look to the source code of [**`get_date_created()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#254-262) it's using the new **`WC_Data`** getter method **`get_prop()`**. In the source code of [**`get_prop()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data.html#600-623) you have this new filter hook possibility to explore:
>
> ```
> $value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this );
> ```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec, WooCommerce have replied directly in the thread https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-time-on-order-backend-broken-since-woo-3/ and have added a new filter, I have posted my new answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-time-on-order-backend-broken-since-woo-3/ working under **WooCommerce Version 6.7.0**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_date_format', 'custom_post_date_column_time');
function custom_post_date_column_time($format)
{
    return __('Y-m-d h:i', 'woocommerce');   
}
```